# Conditionally insert a value in an array when creating a new column

Tags: postgresql, array, postgresql-12

I have some data in a jsonb col that I need to clean and insert into another text array column.

What I have:

```
[
  {
    "v": "birthday"
  },
  {
    "v": "reference"
  }
]
```

What I want (_text):

```
{birthday, reference}
```

My query:

```
select array[col -> 0 ->> 'v', col-> 1 ->> 'v'] from src
```

gives the expected result as above.

However, when the value is null, I want the value not to be inserted i.e. no NULL value nor empty:

```
[
  {
    "v": "birthday"
  }
]
```

should result in

```
{birthday}
```

and not

```
{birthday, [NULL]} -- NULL value
{birthday,} -- Empty string with coalesce
```

How do you conditionally insert an element into an array when creating one, based on the value of the element?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

array_remove() seems to answer my use case (by removing in a 2nd step the null values):

```
select array_remove(array[col -> 0 ->> 'v', col-> 1 ->> 'v'], null) from src
```

Comment: ca you elaborate your answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer